# Are there name restrictions on "Device Instance Path" names?

Tags: winapi, device-driver

I am asking about Win32 Device Instance Path names.  You see these types of paths in the Device Manager.  An example device instance path name is `ACPI\DLLK0706\3&11583659&0` for a keyboard.

Are there any restrictions on Device Instance Path names?  For instance, I am not seeing any path names that exceed 255 characters in length, or use any non-ASCII characters, but are these restrictions real or just a coincidence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Device Instance Path returned by PDO device when it handle  [`IRP_MN_QUERY_ID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/irp-mn-query-id). and exist several restrictions for length (must be less than ***MAX_DEVICE_ID_LEN*** characters long ) and can not use any non-ASCII characters (all must be in ***[0x20, 0x80)*** range and must not be ***';'*** in string )

> If a driver returns an ID with an illegal character, the system will
> bug check. Characters with the following values are illegal in an ID
> for this IRP:
>
> - Less than or equal to 0x20 (' ')
> - Greater than 0x7F
> - Equal to 0x2C (',')
>
> A driver must conform to the following length restrictions for IDs:
>
> - Each hardware ID or compatible ID that a driver returns in this IRP    must be less than **MAX_DEVICE_ID_LEN** characters long. This constant
>   currently has a value of **200** as defined in sdk\inc\cfgmgr32.h.
> - The container ID that a driver returns in this IRP must be formatted    as a globally unique identifier (GUID), and must be
>   **MAX_GUID_STRING_LEN** characters, which includes the null terminator.
> - If a bus driver supplies globally unique instance IDs for its child    devices (that is, the driver sets DEVICE_CAPABILITIES.UniqueID for
>   the devices), then the combination of device ID plus instance ID must
>   be less than **(MAX_DEVICE_ID_LEN - 1)** characters. The operating
>   system    requires the additional character for a path separator.
> - If a bus driver does not supply globally unique instance IDs for its    child devices, then the combination of device ID plus instance
>   ID    must be less than **(MAX_DEVICE_ID_LEN - 28)**. The value of
>   this    equation is currently **172**.